# Grails Domain Classes id

Tags: class, grails, dns

When creating objects in my domain class, id is automatically created - and in my sql database, it is created a column called id as well.

I want that column to be named, for example, "book_id" in class book and "movie_id" in class movie. My question is, how can i change the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly declare the name of the identifier column using `mapping` like this:

```
class Book {
  ..
  static mapping = {
    id column:'book_id'
  }
}
```

Comment: [Link to Grails docs on id](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html)